# Consult for redirecting http to https via HAproxy

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to configure the HAproxy to make it redirect the http traffic to https, but Chrome failed with "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". However, if I used https directly it will work.

For example:
If I typed https://:5443, it will display the page of backend servers.
If I typed http://:5006, it should be redirected but just failed with the error mentioned above.

Here is my config:

```
frontend    simple_webapp    
    mode    http
    bind    *:5006
    bind    *:5443  ssl crt /root/Downloads/simple_webapp_all.pem
    http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc }

    default_backend simple_webapp

backend simple_webapp
    balance     roundrobin
    server      centos8-1 <server ip1>:5006 check 
    server      centos8-2 <server ip2>:5006 check
```

Please correct me if there is any misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

You probably expected that you changed port with scheme, but you haven't. Your request to `http://foo:5006/` gets redirected to `https://foo:5006`, which doesn't support SSL. If you omit port in URL then browsers and web clients are smart enough to use port 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS. That's why it works for default ports.
So try to change your redirect to something like this:

```
http-request redirect prefix https://your_domain_as_explicit_string:5443 unless { ssl_fc }
```

You can experiment with headers, like

```
http-request redirect prefix https://%[hdr(host),regsub(:5006,:5443)] unless { ssl_fc }
```

`hdr(host)` includes in this case `:5006`, so that's changed with `regsub`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I modified the config with your suggestion to add the prefix but chrome still returns error like "This site can’t provide a secure connection192.168.209.133 sent an invalid response. Try running Windows Network Diagnostics. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". Well, the curl -vv returns a rational output though. And just like what you mentioned, the browser is smart enough as once I changed the default http port from 5006 to 80 and https port from 5443 to 443, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Once I changed the port from 5006 to others, it works fine.
No clue what happened on this port.